# Precedence rules is not working in ATG - Endeca Integration - (using precedence_rules.csv)

Tags: atg, endeca

This is our `precedence_rules.csv`:

```
precedence.source_dimension_name,precedence.source_dimval_spec,precedence.target_dimension_name,precedence.type
product.category,Fragrance & Beauty,product.trends,leaf
product.category,Cold Weather,sku.FacetColorCode,leaf
```

**Our requirement:**

When user navigates to `Fragrance & Beauty` via `product.category > Accessories > Fragrance & Beauty`, only then we wanted to display `product.trends` Facet.
Similarly when user navigates to `Cold Weather` via `product.category > Accessories > Cold Weather`, only then we wanted to display `sku.FacetColorCode` Facet.

**Issue:**

The `precedence_rules.csv` is not honoured at all, i.e., when tested in JSP-Ref application, there's no difference before applying `precedence_rules.csv` and after applying it. i.e., we are always getting `sku.FacetColorCode` with `Fragrance & Beauty` also. Similarly, we are getting `product.trends` for `Cold Weather`.

**Requirement#2:** `Cold weather` category belongs to more than one hierarchy as shown below:

```
Accessories > Cold Weather
Collection > Accessories > Cold Weather
Men > Accessories For Men > Cold Weather
```

How to map such scenarios in precedence rules, for example, if I wanted to display `sku.FacetColorCode` only for `Men > Accessories For Men > Cold Weather`, what kind of configuration needs to be done in `precedence_rules.csv` ?

Any faults in the above precedence_rules.csv data?

Thanks

`Prabu

Comment: The `precedence_rules.csv` implementation comes with the Product Catalog Deployment Template. Assuming that you've put this in the correct place and ran both load_baseline_test_data and baseline_update, do you see any values in the projectname.precedence_rules.xml file in the pipeline config folder?

Comment: @radimpe I have put the CSV in <EndecaApp>/config/api_input folder.

We don't run load_baseline_test_data for ATG-Endeca integration (only baseline_update) as the data is alreedy available in CAS when triggered indexing via ATG's ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin component.  AFAIK, pipeline is not affected when CSV files are read for indexing.  Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Looking at the `baseline_update` script in the Deployment Template, it looks like it will take the CSV file and either populate or merge it with the rs_baseline_prules.xml file (my previously mentioned precedence_rules.xml is populated, it would seem, only from DevStudio). Ultimately it will end up as a file(s) in the forge output folder that then feeds into it in the Dgidx process.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar: Have you found solution on this? Did you get to run the precedence rule then? Would be really great help if you can provide the solution... I'm in the same problem

Comment: @HarsH1610 - Nope and I moved on to newer Endeca versions.